# Error in printing from WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, printing, io

I learn how to do this based on this tutorial : http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx

This is the method that my Print Button fired when clicked :

```
PrintManager _pm;
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _pm = new PrintManager(); 
    List<Canvas> pages = new List<Canvas>();
    pages.Add(cnv);

    _pm.Print(pages);
}
```

And this is my PrintManager.cs (`_pm`) :

```
    private const double PAGE_WIDTH = 793.92; //8.27' * 96px
    private const double PAGE_HEIGHT = 1122.24; //11.69' * 96px

    private FixedDocument _document;
    private List<FixedPage> _listOfPages;
    private PageContent _tempPageContent;
    private FixedPage _tempPage;

    public PrintManager()
    {

    }

    public void Print(List<Canvas> pages)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        Canvas temp;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            _document = new FixedDocument();
            _document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new System.Windows.Size(PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT);

            _listOfPages = new List<FixedPage>();

            for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
            {
                _listOfPages.Add(new FixedPage());
                _tempPage = _listOfPages[_listOfPages.Count - 1];
                _tempPage.Width = PAGE_WIDTH;
                _tempPage.Height = PAGE_HEIGHT;

                _tempPage.Children.Add(pages[i]); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE

                _tempPageContent = new PageContent();
                ((IAddChild)_tempPageContent).AddChild(_tempPage);

                _document.Pages.Add(_tempPageContent);
            }

            pd.PrintDocument(_document.DocumentPaginator, "Docdoc");
        }
    }
```

It turns out that there's an error from the problem line (`_tempPage.Children.Add(pages[i]);`) line which says :

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

Any idea why?

Even removing the element from `private List<FixedPage> _listOfPages;` before it's added into the page list didn't help (of course I tried it outside the for loop) with just 1 canvas in the list.

P.S. I need it to be multi-page-able, since my document is usually long (it's a musical scores).

P.S.S. Even printing a canvas with no children manually added, the error was still the same.

P.S.S.S. Another simpler algorithm, even if it's different, is acceptable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to "copy" the canvas content into a new canvas class before sending it to printer.

And clear it from the old canvas. Is anyone can do it better?